# How to change timezone in R?

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

I want to convert time in Japan timezone to time in GMT. However, it doesnot work.

```
> a=strptime("2017-01-01 12:01:02",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Japan")
> a 
[1] "2017-01-01 12:01:02 JST"
> attr(a, "tzone") <- "GMT"
> a
[1] "2017-01-01 12:01:02 JST"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
with_tz(a, "GMT")

#"2017-01-01 03:01:02 GMT"
```

Comment: Can I just use base?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this post:
[Converting time zones](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html)

require(lubridate)

now = Sys.time()

with_tz(now, 'GMT')